# How do I build a SVM classifier in Weka to only consider certain features in the data set?

Tags: svm, weka, chi-squared

I am new to WEKA and I am working on an assignment which currently has 128 different features. I am told to build a SVM classifier on the data and that the classifier should:

1. consider only the top 10 "chi-square" features in the data.
2. the top 10 features should be selected fresh in each fold using 10 fold cross validation.

I have already obtained the top 10 features using the ChiSquaredAttributeEval evaluator. How do I go about building a SVM with points 1&2 in mind?

Edit:How do I show the WEKA 10-fold cross validation workflow diagram for this classifier as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following classifier setup to encapsulate the attribute selection step and the training of your support vector machine on the reduced dataset:

```
meta.FilteredClassifier
|
+- filter: supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection (ChiSquaredAttributeEval + search method)
|
+- classifier: functions.SMO
```